# Get name of active user in script on Mac OS

Tags: macos, mac

I have a perl script ([this script](http://github.com/goerz/activity_logger/blob/master/activity_logger.pl), to be exact) that logs user activity based on idle time on a MacOS X Snow Leopard System. However, with Fast User Switching enabled, more than one user might be logged in at the same time. I want the script to see the computer as 'idle' if another user is active (i.e. using the GUI) through Fast User Switching.

There are numerous ways to figure out when a user logged in. Finding out when a user last "switched" seems more difficult. My solution so far was to look at `/var/log/secure.log`, where Fast User Switching events are logged:

```
tail -200 /var/log/secure.log | grep "User info context values set" | tail -1
```

However, for users running the perl script that are not Admin, `secure.log` will not be readable. Are there any alternative ways to find out which user is currently actively logged in, or what the last Fast User Switching event was?

Of course, the problem could be circumvented if I had a method for finding out the idle time for the user running the script only, not the total idle time of the computer I'm currently getting from `ioreg`. So, I'm open to suggestions there as well.

Thanks!

Comment: What if I only [trigger Fast User Switching](http://superuser.com/questions/45740/fast-user-switching-apple-menu/46308#46308) (`CGSession`), but do not actually switch to another user when the login window is shown? And when using Vine Server, [multiple users could be active simultaneously](http://superuser.com/questions/125636/can-a-mac-be-used-by-multiple-users-at-same-time/125643#125643). In other words: if you're really only tracking a specific user, then maybe you should indeed find a way to see if that user is truly active, rather than trying to determine if someone else might be active?

Comment: In a wild guess I figured maybe `CGSession` might have some useful command line options, but no cigar, I guess: `strings /System/Library/CoreServices/Menu\ Extras/User.menu/Contents/Resources/CGSession | grep "^-"`

Comment: I wouldn't be worried about "multiple users" through VNC sessions.

Comment: You're right of course: I either want to find out whether a specific user is logged in and using the GUI at this moment, or get the idle time for that user only, instead of the whole system.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know how to get time since switch, but you can get the currently active user by checking ownership on /dev/console.  There's probably a better way in Perl, but the stat command'll do it:

```
my $user = `stat -f%Su /dev/console`;
```

Comment: seems to work perfectly!

Comment: Nice! Also, you'll be getting `root` while the login window of Fast User Switching is shown: `while true; do stat -f%Su /dev/console; sleep 2; done`